# Using .rank() to group dataframe in for loop

Tags: pandas, typeerror, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to take a dataframe, filter out non-numeric values, and then group by the 'state' field and rank 'school' in each group. I use the for loop because each state ranked list is exported to excel files with the state name. However, I can't get .rank() to work on the group.

This line of code

```
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['rate1'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

correctly filters the dataframe to only numeric values. But attempting to rank the group dataframes results in error when a non-numeric value is in the data which means it's not working right. When I try to use the parameter numeric_only=True for rank() I get the error "TypeError: rank() got an unexpected keyword argument 'numeric_only'"

```
# In[24]:
import pandas as pd

# In[25]:
data = {'school_name': ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5','s6', 's7', 's8'],
        'state': ['tx', 'wa', 'wa', 'ak', 'tx', 'ak', 'tx', 'tx'],
        'rate1': ['text', 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 8, 6],
       'rate2' : [2, 1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# In[26]:
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['rate1'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
print(df)

# Out[26]:
  school_name state rate1  rate2
1          s2    wa     4      1
2          s3    wa     2      6
3          s4    ak     1      3
4          s5    tx     5      2
5          s6    ak     7      4
6          s7    tx     8      3
7          s8    tx     6      8

# In[27]:
grouped = df.groupby('state')
print(grouped.groups)

# Out[27]:
{'ak': Int64Index([3, 5], dtype='int64'), 'tx': Int64Index([4, 6, 7], dtype='int64'), 'wa': Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')}

# In[29]:
for name, group in grouped:
    df['rank1'] = df.groupby('state')['rate1'].rank(method='min', numeric_only=True)
    df['rank2'] = df.groupby('state')['rate2'].rank(method='min')
    df['final_rank'] = df['rank1'] + df['rank2']
    df = df.sort_values(by=['state', 'final_rank'])


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-1af08256aabd> in <module>
      4 for name, group in grouped:
----> 5     df['rank1'] = df.groupby('state')['rate1'].rank(method='min', numeric_only=True)
      6     df['rank2'] = df.groupby('state')['rate2'].rank(method='min')
      7     df['final_rank'] = df['rank1'] + df['rank2']

TypeError: rank() got an unexpected keyword argument 'numeric_only'
```

So in Out[26] I see it's correctly filtering out s1 which has non-numeric value for 'rate1'. Similar result for print(grouped.groups). However, if I run the first df['rank1'] without numeric_only=True, I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. If i add numeric_only=True, I get the unexpected keyword argument shown above. How do I reconcile the clean df with the group? I realize ranking on a dataframe instead of a group would work, but I need the for loop to export file for each state group.

Comment: [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) doesn't have an argument `numeric_only`. `Dataframe.rank` does

Comment: But even so [['rate1']] will lead to the same error. This [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19560) is somewhat related. The other big issue here is that subsetting to the numeric values **does not** change the dtype of the column, so it's still an `object`, which causes issues for rank.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. So instead of subsetting to numeric values, what can I do to filter out the strings in df so I can use rank with groupby?